# Google Map Scrolling Issue

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a hotel search page on my website which consists of a map on one half of the screen and (scrollable) search results on the other half. I don't know whats changed, but now when I try to zoom in the map using the scroll wheel, I get the following message:

[image]

And in addition to that, the search results on the right side are being scrolled (even though the mouse is over the map).

Here is the css of both containers:

```css
.map-container {
  width: 45%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  top:115px;
}

.results-container{
  margin-left:45%;
  width:55%;
  padding-top:0px;
  margin-top:65px;
}
```

If I set the results-container position to fixed, the map scrolls normally but I can't scroll the results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow zooming only with scroll in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694192/allow-zooming-only-with-scroll-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a scrollable page, google maps won't use the scrollwheel to scroll the map by default (changed within the last 12 months or so in the API, can't remember exactly when).

Add the following to your map options:

```
gestureHandling:'greedy'
```

More information:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction